# ajax jquery datatable not return datas on table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, datatables

I am  using jquery datatable use it from external cdn

```
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

and my table is

```
  <table class="table table-bordered data-table" id="blocked_list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            </table>
```

and cal this in jquery function

```
@section('script')
<script>
$('#blocked_list').DataTable({
    "ajax": "{{ route('user.sold_products') }}",
    "columns": [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'buyer_id'},
        { data: 'seller_id' },
    ]
});
</script>
@endsection
```

here i think i done correctly but the data not displayed inside my table and i call data from my controller is:

```
  public function all(){
      $user = Auth::user();
      $block = Block::all();
      $bl = Block::where('buyer_id',$user->id)->get();
      return Response::json([
            'data' => $block
      ], 200);
    }
```

my controler having following values inside data variable

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"seller_id":12,"buyer_id":11,"email":"","created_at":"2017-06-01 11:37:54","updated_at":"2017-06-01 11:37:54"},{"id":2,"seller_id":10,"buyer_id":11,"email":"","created_at":"2017-06-01 14:20:51","updated_at":"2017-06-01 14:20:51"}]}
```

when thevalues not displayed inside myy laravel table i doknow why can anyone please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Try `{"data":[["id":1]]}` instead of `{"data":[{"id":1}]}`

Comment: can you show me the full js code

Comment: Sry That Was Wrong, Try This First And Tell... Change your tr tags like

                `<tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>buyer_id</th>
                    <th>seller_id</th>
                </tr>`

Comment: try adding `"dataType": "json"` to your ajax

Comment: What does the dev console show? Is the ajax call being done? check the network tab in the dev console.